# Angular treeview delete selected node

Tags: angularjs, treeview

I am using angular `treeview` to build a tree using AngularJS. I am able to add a new child, as well as new node in my application.

1. I am able to add new node as well as child for selected node
2. I am able to Edit the selected node as well as child

Below jsfiddle link have Add/Edit node.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/48cafgsu/
```

I need to delete the selected node.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello i updated your fiddle to be able to delete a node

https://jsfiddle.net/48cafgsu/56/

```
     Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments,
      L = a.length,
      ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
      what = a[--L];
      while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) != -1) {
        this.splice(ax, 1);
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  var getSubMenuItem = function(subMenuItems, node) {
    console.log(subMenuItems)
    console.log(node)

    var current_node = subMenuItems;

    if (subMenuItems) {
      for (var i = 0; i < subMenuItems.length; i++) {
        if (subMenuItems[i].id == node.id) {
          current_node = current_node.remove(node);
          console.log('removed')
         // subMenuItems =current_node
          return

        }

        if(subMenuItems[i].children.length>0){

        getSubMenuItem(subMenuItems[i].children,node)


        }



      }
    }
  };
```